# Angular 5 create parents template

Tags: html, angular

In my html, I have multiple instances where I am writing:

```
<div class="col-11 col-md-10 pb-2">
    <div class="card w-100">
        <div class="card-body row">
            elements that change here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

which seems counterintuitive considering the purpose of Angular, so how would I possibly write some variation of:

```
<outer-elements>
    standard inner elements
</outer-elements>
```

A component or directive doesn't seem to do the tick (to the best of my knowledge thus far) because the inner elements don't follow a specific template/format that can easily be input.

Comment: are you wanting things like a nav bar and footer? or a whole border for example?

Comment: you can use `ng-content`

Comment: @mast3rd3mon no, those outer components simply work to apply classes that are necessary for scaling/breakpoints

Comment: i dont think you can, it wouldnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is named `transclusion` in Angular. It let a component define a general structure while injecting content inside of it (multiple contents are possible).

Your component template should look like :

```
<div class="col-11 col-md-10 pb-2">
  <div class="card w-100">
    <div class="card-body row">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Take a look at [this very nice tutorial on it](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content) I did follow a while ago to understand this concept.